# Delphi: How to read byte and delete it

Tags: delphi

I have variable:

```
data: TIdBytes;
```

it contains some amount of data.

How to read first byte of "data", and delete the first byte from "data" ?

And yes, I will do it again and again. Until "data" will be empty.

I will use the copied byte with "IF"

```
if $0F = Copiedbyte then
 do_somthing;
```

maybe deleting is not so necessary, I just can copy next byte..

I don't need loop, i just need to copy one byte the do something with it, for example save for later use.

Comment: need more info. What are you going to do with the rest of the data after you have read and deleted the first byte?  Read and delete the first byte again? Pass it off to something else?

Comment: Why do you need to delete anything. Just iterate over the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to delete anything and it seems wasteful to do so. It would make your code messier and cost CPU time.

Just iterate over the array of bytes:

```
var
  b: byte;
....
for b in data do
  dosomething(b);
```

If you don't want to do this in a loop, keep track of the index of the next byte to be processed. Every time you process a byte, increment the index.

```
function GetNext(
  const data: TIdBytes;
  var Index: Integer; 
  var b: Byte
): Boolean;
begin
  Result := Index<=high(data);
  if Result then
  begin
    b := data[Index];
    inc(Index);
  end;
end;
```

Initialise an index variable to 0 and keep calling this function, extracting one byte at a time, until it returns False.

Comment: I don't need loop, i just need to copy one byte the do something with it, for example save for later use.

Comment: +1 for the answer and for figuring out what OP meant by "I don't need loop". Being clair voyant as well as Santa?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there's no real need to delete, just loop through each byte in the array:

```
for i := Low(Data) to High(Data) do
begin
  if data[i] = CopiedByte then
     Do_Somthing;
end
```

Comment: I don't need loop, i just need to copy one byte the do something with it, for example save for later use.

Answer (score 0):

how about converting it into an array of bytes, then remove the first index and merge the rest back together?

Comment: TIdBytes is an array of bytes. After that your answer just repeats the question.